# How can I read the file which doesn't have Filename extension in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, file-extension

I am dealing with climate dataset in R, where I downloaded yearly Temp/Precip observation by the globe from here: [climate data archive](http://climate.geog.udel.edu/~climate/html_pages/download.html#ghcn_T_P_clim3), and example datasets can be found [yearly temperature data for all countires](http://jmp.sh/pVBpD1w) and another one is [yearly precipitation data for all countries](http://jmp.sh/sDvll6B). However, the format of this data doesn't have fileName extension, and its respective filename extension was forgotten or missing. I tried `base::scan()` to load them in R, but the output is not desired. Because each file must have 14 fixed columns, but if I used `scan()`, it will read 7 column only, which is not desired for me. Is there any better function for reading the file without specific filename extension? Any idea?

Here is how list of climate data looks like:

list.files("stella/data/air_temp_1980_2014/", recursive = TRUE)

```
 [1] "air_temp.1980" "air_temp.1981" "air_temp.1982" "air_temp.1983"
 [5] "air_temp.1984" "air_temp.1985" "air_temp.1986" "air_temp.1987"
 [9] "air_temp.1988" "air_temp.1989" "air_temp.1990" "air_temp.1991"
[13] "air_temp.1992" "air_temp.1993" "air_temp.1994" "air_temp.1995"
[17] "air_temp.1996" "air_temp.1997" "air_temp.1998" "air_temp.1999"
[21] "air_temp.2000" "air_temp.2001" "air_temp.2002" "air_temp.2003"
[25] "air_temp.2004" "air_temp.2005" "air_temp.2006" "air_temp.2007"
[29] "air_temp.2008" "air_temp.2009" "air_temp.2010" "air_temp.2011"
[33] "air_temp.2012" "air_temp.2013" "air_temp.2014"
```

Here is how `scan()` produce its output:

```
>scan(file = "stella/data/air_temp_1980_2014/air_temp.1980", sep = "", skip = 1)

[1] -179.75   68.75  -27.00  -28.20  -27.20  -21.60   -9.00
   [8]    0.60    2.80    1.90   -0.20  -11.90  -22.70  -25.10
  [15] -179.75   68.25  -27.80  -28.50  -27.50  -22.00   -9.50
  [22]    0.40    3.00    1.80   -0.80  -12.70  -23.60  -26.80
  [29] -179.75   67.75  -26.80  -26.60  -25.70  -20.50   -8.00
  [36]    2.70    6.00    4.00    0.50  -12.20  -23.20  -27.30
  [43] -179.75   67.25  -29.10  -28.40  -27.50  -22.30   -9.70
  [50]    2.20    6.20    3.30   -1.30  -15.40  -26.40  -31.10
  [57] -179.75   66.75  -25.40  -23.80  -22.90  -18.20   -6.10
  [64]    3.80    8.60    6.00    1.10  -11.50  -22.30  -27.20
```

**Desired output**:

```
> desired output
         Long    Lat   Jan   Feb   Mar April   May   Jun   Jul
1     -179.75  68.75 -27.0 -28.2 -27.2 -21.6  -9.0   0.6   2.8
2     -179.75  68.25 -27.8 -28.5 -27.5 -22.0  -9.5   0.4   3.0
3     -179.75  67.75 -26.8 -26.6 -25.7 -20.5  -8.0   2.7   6.0
4     -179.75  67.25 -29.1 -28.4 -27.5 -22.3  -9.7   2.2   6.2
5     -179.75  66.75 -25.4 -23.8 -22.9 -18.2  -6.1   3.8   8.6
6     -179.75  66.25 -21.5 -18.9 -17.2 -14.0  -2.3   3.4   9.2
7     -179.75  65.75 -20.2 -17.9 -17.1 -13.2  -2.2   4.3  10.1
8     -179.75  65.25 -20.0 -18.7 -17.4 -14.1  -2.4   4.3  10.5
9     -179.75 -16.75  27.4  28.3  27.9  27.2  25.7  24.9  24.7
10    -179.75 -84.75 -18.9 -27.9 -38.6 -41.5 -41.2 -44.4 -45.2
11    -179.75 -85.25 -23.9 -33.8 -45.1 -47.9 -47.7 -50.4 -51.5
12    -179.75 -85.75 -22.8 -33.5 -45.2 -48.1 -47.7 -49.9 -51.4
13    -179.75 -86.25 -24.3 -35.5 -47.7 -50.6 -50.2 -52.1 -53.8
14    -179.75 -86.75 -25.5 -37.1 -49.6 -52.6 -52.1 -53.8 -55.7
15    -179.75 -87.25 -26.2 -38.1 -50.9 -53.8 -53.2 -54.8 -56.8
16    -179.75 -87.75 -26.7 -39.0 -51.9 -54.8 -54.3 -55.7 -57.9
```

I want to read all list of files in R. How can I read above data correctly in R as I expected? Any idea?

Comment: If you have fixed-width data, use `read.fwf()` or `readr::read_fwf()` to import your data. Whether or not a file has a particular extension is irrelevant to R. It just matters what's inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filename extension in itself doesn't mean much. It is there to signify how the data in the file is ordered. You should open the file in a text-editor to figure out how it is represented.

From the looks of it, and according to [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49562987/6822618), it might be a tab-delimited csv file. So the way to import it into R is to use the CSV-related input functions, like `read.csv` or `data.table::fread`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a tab delimited file (confirm by adding `.txt` extension). If you add a .csv extension to each of the files and then read them in explicitly using whitespace as the delimiter, it should work fine. This may be tedious but is likely your best option, as files without an appropriate extension are confusing in their own right.

Be cautious though because the column names are not preserved. To avoid the first row getting stored as column names you need to pass a vector of names to the function as well.

```
name_vector <- c("Long", "Lat", ... )

x <- read.csv("path/precip.1980.csv", sep = "", col.names = name_vector)
```

#### edit:

since you've already scanned the data in, you should be able to just paste a ".csv" to the end of each element in the file list vector instead of having to do it manually. However, `read.csv()` will not work without an extension so it has to be done at some point.

```
# store file list
filelist <- list.files("stella/data/air_temp_1980_2014/", recursive = TRUE)

# paste extension
filelist <- paste0(filelist, ".csv")
```

Then you could iteratively read the files in with my code from above. Here's an example of a solution that could work. do that for you.

```
dat <- lapply(filelist, function (x) {
   read.csv(x, sep = "", col.names = name_vector)
})
```

I haven't explicitly tested this solution, and it still likely will present errors because of the column names issue. If you'd provide a proper [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it would be much easier to troubleshoot these issues for you.

Comment: I wasn't telling you it doesn't have an extension, I was telling you how to fix it. Alternatively, I edited my post to give you a more automated way of doing it. There may still be problems but without a proper reprex I can't play with it to figure out what those are. If you take the code from my original answer + edit you should be set, aside from figuring out the column names issue. @Dan